# How to use SoundRequestFeedback to tell if a sound is being played or not?

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to reference the `.playing` function in `SoundRequestFeedback.h`([link to file](https://github.com/Pontusun/CIS700_Team2/blob/master/catkin_ws/devel/include/sound_play/SoundRequestFeedback.h)) to allow my system to finish speaking before executing the rest of the code but I can't seem to figure out how to properly do that.

In my header file I declared `sound_play::SoundRequestFeedback_<ContainerAllocator> v` and proceeded to try and do

```
ROS_INFO("%d", v.playing); // prints False<->0 
sound_play::SoundClient.say("This is a test message"); //Says "This is a test message"
while(v.playing){}
    //stays in a loop while the system is saying the message
ROS_INFO("%d", v.playing); // also prints False, but does so while the system is still saying the message.
```

so `v.playing` always returns 0 and I don't know why. Does anyone know why ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259340/how-to-use-soundrequestfeedback-to-tell-if-a-sound-is-being-played-or-not?/) by [Azul](https://answers.ros.org/users/30021/azul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-04-16**:
Could you link to the files that you are referring to?

**Comment by [Azul](https://answers.ros.org/users/30021/azul/) on 2017-04-16**:
Yes, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think this is possible as the sound_play::Soundclient only publishes requests but does not listen for any feedback.
I also don't understand your code. How is your feedback-object linked to the Soundclient? Does this piece of code even compile? (and btw: .playing is not a function)

You could run the soundplay_node in sound_play. This nodes offers an SoundRequest-ActionServer to which you can send your goal and wait for the result. In my experiements, the result-message came around 2 seconds after the sound really finished, but you could check that with your setup.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Azul](https://answers.ros.org/users/30021/azul/) on 2017-04-18**:
Hi, the piece of code compiled and it always returned 0. Could you provide the code example from your experiments ? I looked at the tutorials on ros.wiki but I'm not quite sure how to apply it to my case